# Python: Equivalent of Inheritance with Closures

Tags: python, oop, functional-programming, closures

I'm trying to transition from OOP to functional programming.  I have the following situation: (the variables make no sense - they're just examples).

```
Funcs = namedtuple('Funcs', ('func1', 'func2'))

def thing_1(alpha, beta):
    gamma = alpha+beta
    def func_1(x):
        return x+gamma
    def func_2(x):
        return x*gamma
    return Funcs(func_1, func_2)

def thing_2(alpha, beta):
    gamma = alpha+beta
    delta = alpha*beta
    def func_1(x):
        return x+gamma
    def func_2(x):
        return x*gamma+delta
    return Funcs(func_1, func_2)
```

Now, we have some code duplication: `func_1` is the same in both things.  Both things also initialize gamma the same way.

If I use OOP, it's obvious what to do - make a `BaseThing`, make `func_2` abstract, and have Thing1 override method `func_2`, and `Thing2` override both the `func_2` method and `__init__` (which will call `BaseThing.__init__` then initialize delta).

Using closures, it's not obvious to me - what's the best way to do the same thing?

Comment: Just move `func_1`  outside of `thing_1`  and `thing_2`.

Comment: Can't - it uses gamma, which is only defined within thing_1, thing_2.

Comment: Because Python already has a perfectly fine object system, there's no need to fake one out of closures. Functional programming can work alongside OO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic way is to create a separate closure for `func_1`:

```
def gammafied_func_1(gamma):
    def func_1(x):
        return x + gamma
    return func_1

def thing_1(alpha, beta):
    gamma = alpha+beta
    def func_2(x):
        return x*gamma
    return Funcs(gammafied_func_1(gamma), func_2)
```

This sort of thing comes up often enough that there is a higher-order function for it, called [partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial), referring to the general concept of partial application.  That lets you use one function to create a smaller function with some of its parameters "frozen":

```
from functools import partial

def func_1(gamma, x):
    return x + gamma

def thing_1(alpha, beta):
    gamma = alpha+beta
    def func_2(x):
        return x*gamma
    return Funcs(partial(func_1, gamma), func_2)
```

Here, `partial(func_1, gamma)` returns a new function that has the same body as `func_1`, except it only takes an `x` parameter and `gamma` has been "frozen" to the local `gamma` inside `thing_1`.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand your specific example, but in a more abstract way, the difference between OOP and FP can be summarized as follows:

- in OOP

  - object is a unit
  - parametrization is achieved by virtual methods
  - specialization is achieved by inheritance

In other words, the behavior of an object depends on (or "is parametrized by") virtual methods it calls. To fix (or "specialize") a certain set of "parameters" (=methods), you extend the object.

- in FP

  - function is a unit
  - parametrization is achieved by functional parameters
  - specialization is achieved by partial application

To parametrize a function you pass other functions to it. To fix a set of parameters you create a new function which is the base func with partially applied params.

Illustration:

```
# OOP style

class Animal:
    def voice(self):
        pass
    def greet(self, person):
        return '%s, %s!' % (self.voice(), person)

class Dog(Animal):
    def voice(self):
        return 'woof'

class Cat(Animal):
    def voice(self):
        return 'meow'

print Dog().greet('master')
print Cat().greet('master')

# FP style

def greet(voice, person):
    return '%s, %s!' % (voice(), person)

from functools import partial

dogGreet = partial(greet, lambda: 'woof')
catGreet = partial(greet, lambda: 'meow')

print dogGreet('master')
print catGreet('master')
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it's not particularly neat.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from collections import namedtuple

Funcs = namedtuple('Funcs', ('func1', 'func2'))

def thing_1(alpha, beta):
    gamma = alpha+beta
    def func_1(x):
        return x+gamma
    def func_2(x):
        return x*gamma
    return Funcs(func_1, func_2)

t1 = thing_1(3, 7)
print t1.func1(10), t1.func2(10)

def thing_2(alpha, beta):
    delta = alpha*beta
    t = thing_1(alpha, beta)
    def func_2(x):
        return t.func2(x) + delta
    return Funcs(t.func1, func_2)

t2 = thing_2(4, 6)
print t2.func1(10), t2.func2(10)
```

**output**

```
20 100
20 124
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope works:

```
In [22]: def f1(x):
   ....:     return x + gamma
   ....: 

In [23]: def t1():
   ....:     return f1("foo")
   ....: 

In [24]: gamma = "bar"

In [25]: t1()
Out[25]: 'foobar'
```

`f1` closes over `gamma`.

Comment: Ok, but now gamma belongs to the module and not to t1 - so if I were to call another t1(), I wouldn't be able to give it a different value of gamma - so it doesn't really solve my problem.

Comment: Well, what *is* your problem?

Comment: Problem is to avoid code reuse while maintaining the same functionality.  This doesn't maintain the same functionality because it makes gamma a global variable, shared between thing_1 and thing_2.